# Cannot catch mouse events after having a certain transparency as a JavaFX Scene fill

Tags: javafx, transparency, scene

I am trying to create an anchor pane that is transparent but you can drag it in the same time.

I set the stage transparent, I give the scene a transparent fill, and I set up the `OnMousePressed` etc on the pane.

The program behaves very strangely for me. There is a certain threshold for the transparency: if you are below this threshold, the pane will not catch mouse events. If above, then it will.

I give you an example. When I was writing this example, I found that the threshold here is between 0.5 and 0.6. It means: If I set the transparency of the fill to 0.5 or below the window will not be dragable, if to 0.6 or above, it will be.

My test code:

```
public class Main extends Application {

    Stage primaryStage;

    class Delta {
        double x, y;
    }

    final Delta dragDelta = new Delta();

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
        primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);

        showMain();
    }

    public void showMain() {

        AnchorPane ap = new AnchorPane();

        ap.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                dragDelta.x = primaryStage.getX() - mouseEvent.getScreenX();
                dragDelta.y = primaryStage.getY() - mouseEvent.getScreenY();
            }
        });
        ap.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                primaryStage.setX(mouseEvent.getScreenX() + dragDelta.x);
                primaryStage.setY(mouseEvent.getScreenY() + dragDelta.y);
            }
        });

        Scene scene = new Scene(ap);
        scene.setFill(Color.rgb(252, 0, 4, 0.6));
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

Can you explain or reproduce this behavior? Thank you!

Comment: try [`setPickOnBounds(true)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setPickOnBounds-boolean-).  If it is not what you are looking for, provide an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: hi, no, I think that method is not the one for now. I created the mcve so you can see the issue better.

Comment: can you reproduce it? or is it then a platform problem? if the post is still not good enough let me know

Answer (score 0):

This is not a bug - it's a feature. The general rule is that you cannot click on things which you cannot see. I'd prefer it if this decision would have been left to the programmer.